# opencv::Mat structure for using depth maps?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am reading an image in to a `cv::Mat.`

```
cv::Mat depth_map = cv::imread("patio_depth.jpg", -1);
```

The Mat is then passed to this function: (that gets xyz coordinates from a depth map).

```
inline cv::Point3d getPoint3D(int x, int y) const
{
    cv::Point3d point;
    point.x = depth_map.at<cv::Vec3f>(y, x)[0];
    point.y = depth_map.at<cv::Vec3f>(y, x)[1];
    point.z = depth_map.at<cv::Vec3f>(y, x)[2];

    return point;
}
```

Which causes an assertion error.

```
Assertion failed <dims <= 2 && data && <unsigned>i0 <unsigned>size.p[0] && <unsigned><i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels>
```

in \core\mat.hpp

I assume that this means the Mat I am using is incompatible with the function, but what Mat structure WILL work? Or do I need to convert it somehow before I pass it through?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is because I am using a jpg image. (as answered on opencv forum)

'You are reading a JPG image, therefore you get a BGR image in depth_map, not a float. You should use cv::Vec3b instead of cv::Vec3f to access pixels.'

works like a charm.